# How to copy part of a two-dimensional array in to a one-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

**This code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int arr[3][3] = {
                    1,2,3,
                    4,5,6,
                    7,8,9
                };


int *arry = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
*arry = memcpy(arry, arr[1], 3 *sizeof(int));

 int t;
 for(t = 0 ; t < 3 ; t++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d \t", arry[t]);
    }
}
```

**is producing this output:**

   
 7280624
    5
    6
    Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 0.011 s
    Press any key to continue.

Why is it not copying the first value correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is copying the first value correctly, but

```
*arry = memcpy(arry, arr[1], 3 *sizeof(int));
```

you are overwriting it with the return value of `memcpy`.

Just call

```
memcpy(arry, arr[1], 3 *sizeof(int));
```

or assign the return value to a different variable if you want to check it (pointless, since `memcpy` returns its first argument).

Answer (score 0):

[memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) returns a void*.

You are assigning the void* returned by memcpy to the value pointed to by arry. This is giving you a strange value when trying to read that value. Just call memcpy

```
memcpy(arry, arr[1], 3 * sizeof(int));
```